# Шаблон для создания вопросов-соревнований

Tags: поддержка, faq

- Есть какой-либо формат, который подходит для вопросов-соревнований?
- Есть ли шаблон, который я могу взять за основу для подготовки своего соревнования?

Answer (score 5):

Для написании вопроса-соревнования, вы можете следовать следующему формату.

---

## Введение

Кратко опишите задачу соревнования и предысторию, при необходимости. В описании, постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

- Чем интересно это соревнование?
- Являетесь ли вы автором соревнования? При необходимости, укажите ссылки на источники.

Одного параграфа будет достаточно.

## Соревнование

Опишите соревнование во всех деталях. Описание любого соревнование должно включать:

- Полное описание всего, что подается на вход.
- Полное описание всего, что должно быть на выходе.
- Полное описание того, как связаны входные данные и результат на выходе.

Постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

- Есть ли исключительные случаи? Если да, то как с ними поступать?
- Как определить победителя соревнования?
- На основе каких критериев следует оценивать ответы?

Будьте лаконичны: максимум важных нюансов о соревновании и минимум ненужных  деталей.

## Пример входных и выходных данных

Предоставьте как минимум один пример корректных входных данных и желаемого результата на выходе. Убедитесь, что примеры соответствуют вашему описанию соревнования.

Входные данные:

> Пример входных данных

Результат на выходе:

> Пример ожидаемого результата на выходе

...

---

### ***Разметка Markdown для копирования***

```
# Введение

Кратко опишите задачу соревнования и предысторию, при необходимости. В описании, постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

 - Чем интересно это соревнование?
 - Являетесь ли вы автором соревнования? При необходимости, укажите ссылки на источники.

Одного параграфа будет достаточно.

# Соревнование

Опишите соревнование во всех деталях. Описание любого соревнование должно включать:

 - Полное описание всего, что подается на вход.
 - Полное описание всего, что должно быть на выходе. 
 - Полное описание того, как связаны входные данные и результат на выходе.

Постарайтесь рассказать коллегам:

- Есть ли исключительные случаи? Если да, то как с ними поступать? 
- Как определить победителя соревнования?
- На основе каких критериев следует оценивать ответы?

Будьте лаконичны: максимум важных нюансов о соревновании с минимум ненужных  деталей.

# Пример входных и выходных данных

Предоставьте как минимум один пример корректных входных данных и желаемого результата на выходе. Убедитесь, что примеры соответствуют вашему описанию соревнования.

Входные данные:

> Пример входных данных

Результат на выходе:

> Пример ожидаемого результата на выходе    

...
```