# Песочница для вопросов–соревнований

Tags: поддержка, faq

Создание понятного и хорошо проработанного вопроса–соревнования — сложная задача. Чтобы увеличить ваши шансы на успех, вы можете опубликовать вашу заготовку ответом в этом «вопросе–песочнице» ([что такое «песочница»](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development))), чтобы получить отзыв сообщества.

Для получения отзыва, пожалуйста, опубликуйте заготовку вашего соревнования в том виде, в котором вы планируете опубликовать его на основном сайте. Вы можете добавить несколько заметок, акцентирующих внимание на том, где бы вы хотели услышать мысли других участников. Вместе мы сделаем ваше соревнование лучше. Как только вы почувствуете, что ваше соревнование готово, опубликуйте его на основном сайте! После публикации на основном сайте, *замените содержимое вашего ответа в этом вопросе на ссылку на соревнование на основном сайте и удалите ваш ответ здесь на Мете.*

#### Дополнительно

- [Шаблон для вопросов-соревнований](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11257/6)
- [Страница справки о вопросах-соревнованиях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf)

Comment: О отлично прям как на code-golf.SE ;)

Comment: @Kromster И то, и другое! =) Это заимствовано с Code Golf SE. Там делают именно так: добавляют ссылку на вопрос на основном сайте и удаляют ответ.

Comment: @Kromster Подскажите, стало лучше?

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо! Я бы все–таки оставил как было. На Code Golf SE вполне себе хорошие правила. Удаление, как я понимаю, необходимо, чтобы в песочнице были видны только активные заявки.

Comment: Да, верно! Надо вставить ссылку на основной стай в тело ответа, а затем нажать «удалить».

Comment: Если это так, то надо добавить пояснение зачем это делать, какой в этом смысл для участников с репутацией меньше 10к (которые удаленного не видят)